# JQuery datepicker doesn't allow to choose a day bigger than 12

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have an edit form with two TextBoxFor components for start and end date.

I store the dates in the SQL server database in the following form:

```
12.4.2014 0:00:00 (day, month, year)
```

Both fields have the same initial format (second parameter of the TextBoxFor component) and use the same format for the picked date from the datepicker:

```
<script >
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker, #datepicker2").datepicker(
     {dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy 0:00:00' }); //format of the picked date
    });
</script> 

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date_start,"{0:dd.MM.yyyy 0:00:00}", new {id = "datepicker" }) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date_end,"{0:dd.MM.yyyy 0:00:00}", new { id = "datepicker2" } ) %>
```

This works, if I select a date, where the day is smaller or equal to 12, which would mean, it treats the first number as a month value. Otherwise it displays the "The field X must be a date." validation message.

Did I forget to set the format somewhere or is the cause of the problem something else?

EDIT: Tried the date 12.31.2014 0:00:00, which is valid on the client's side. It definitely treats the first number as the month and the second as the day, since 12.32.2014 isn't recognized as valid.
So there is something wrong with the datepicker's date format nob being used.

Comment: 1 - 12? You are probably getting the month value. You may want to try to recheck the date format

Comment: Why are there (zero) times included if you are picking dates?

Comment: I'd like them to be appended to the dates as a default value. But I guess they aren't the problem, since picking a two digit day-date, which is smaller or equal to 12 works (for example, picking 02.04.2014 and 12.12.2014 works).

Answer (score 0):

You must know that date is text. so you need in model make it string then in controler convert it to datetime.

model:

```
public class DeviceCheckViewModel
{

    public string dtStart { get; set; }
    public string dtEnd { get; set; }
  
}
```

controller
`

```
 public ActionResult DataReload(alyans.Models.DeviceCheckViewModel deviceCheckViewModel)
        {
          
            Int64 compID = (Int64)Session["CompanyID"];

            //подготовка даты
            DateTime DateFrom;
            DateTime DateTo;
            string dateFrom = null;
            string dateTo = null;
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            if (deviceCheckViewModel.dtStart == "")
                dateFrom = "";
            else
            {
                DateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(deviceCheckViewModel.dtStart, "dd.mm.yyyy", provider); ;
                dateFrom = DateFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
            if (deviceCheckViewModel.dtEnd == "")
                dateTo = "";
            else
            {
                DateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(deviceCheckViewModel.dtEnd, "dd.mm.yyyy", provider); ;
                dateTo = DateTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
```

`
view

```
           @using (Html.BeginForm("DataReload", "DeviceCheck", FormMethod.Post))
    {
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dtStart,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dtEnd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
</div>
<div>
<input type = "submit" name = "name" value = "Применить" class="button"/>


</div>
}
```